# Eclipse C printf() fail

Tags: c, eclipse, printf

I just installed Eclipse for c++ and I have a problem with the `printf()` function.
My code should start by printing, "Give the number" but it doesn't. If I type 4,this is what I get:

```
4

Give the number:

I am number 1

I am number 2

I am number 3

I am number 4
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int n=0,i;
    printf("Give the number:\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        printf("I am number %d\n",i);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Seems the "terminal" Eclipse uses isn't line-buffered. Try adding an `fflush(stdout);` after the first `printf`.

Comment: Or use `setvbuf(stdout, 0, _IOLBF, 0);` to make it line buffered (before the first use of `printf()`).

Comment: I copied the answers you posted in your comments to make it an answer, since I'm sometimes browsing the unanswered questions to see if I can help, and it's confusing to have "unanswered" questions which actually already have an answer. I hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[There are three different kinds of buffering strategies:](http://www.aquaphoenix.com/ref/gnu_c_library/libc_119.html)

- Characters written to or read from an unbuffered stream are transmitted individually to or from the file as soon as possible.
- Characters written to or read from a line buffered stream are transmitted to or from   the file in blocks when a newline character is encountered.
- Characters written to or read from a fully buffered stream are transmitted to or from the file in blocks of arbitrary size.

As Daniel Fischer and Jonathan Leffler pointed out, it seems your terminal is initially fully buffered, which means you have to use `fflush(stdout);` to transmit your stream to the terminal or change its configuration with `setvbuf(stdout, 0, _IOLBF, 0);`.